# Java | Keychain shop exercise | Keychain number variable in main doesn't want to store

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to solve [this](http://www.programmingbydoing.com/a/keychains2.html) exercise and the final keychain number keeps returning 0. I want to store the keychain count in main.

Below is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class functionCall_inMain {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    int price=10;
    int count=0;
```

this is the problem. It keeps initializing it with 1 and if I choose to see the order details it keeps showing me that 0 keychains have been added.

I made another version where "count" is a global variable and the methods don't pass any variables - checkout(), add_keychain() and so on.

I want to try this version with add_keychain(int) and view order(int,int)  where the methods hold variables, yet it keeps returning 0 every time.

```
    System.out.println("Ye olde keychain shop");
    System.out.println("1. Add keychains to order");
    System.out.println("2. Remove keychains from order");
    System.out.println("3. View current order");
    System.out.println("4. Checkout");
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice=sc.nextInt();



    while(choice!=4){
    if(choice==1){add_keychain(count);}                    
    if(choice==2){remove_keychain(count);}                 
    if(choice==3){view_order(count,price);}           
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
    choice=sc.nextInt();    }

    checkout(count,price);   //in my other version this would be checkout() and so on

}


public static int add_keychain(int count){
System.out.println("How many keys to add? You have "+count+" keys.");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int x=sc.nextInt();
count=count+x;
return count;}



    public int remove_keychain(int count){
```

I tried `this.count=count;` and it doesn't work. I even placed it in a non-static method. Is there any other way I can store the "count" variable in main?

```
    System.out.println("How many keys to remove? You have "+count+" keys.");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int y=sc.nextInt();
    count=count-y;
    return count;
}

    public static void view_order(int count, int price){

        System.out.println("You have "+count +" keys.");
        System.out.println("Price is "+price+" per key.");
        System.out.println("Overall price is: "+count*price+" dollars");}

 public static void checkout(int count,int price){
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Checking out. Insert name: ");
 String x=sc.next();
 System.out.println(x);
 System.out.println("You have "+count +" keys.");
 System.out.println("Price is "+price+" dollars per key.");
 System.out.println("Overall price is: "+count*price+" dollars");
 System.out.println("Thank you.");  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you pass the `count` variable in the methods:

```
public static int add_keychain(int count) {
```

which is not necessary if you declared it as a (static) field. Because Java passes `int` parameters by value, `count` is another variable *inside* the method, wholly different from the `count` declared as (what you call) a global variable.

There are two options to solve this:

1. Declare `count` as a static field: `private static int count` and remove the `count` parameter from all methods.
2. Change these lines so that `count` gets updated:

   ```
   if(choice==1){add_keychain(count);}                    
   if(choice==2){remove_keychain(count);}
   ```

   to

   ```
   if(choice==1){ count = add_keychain(count);}                    
   if(choice==2){ count = remove_keychain(count);}
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I went with the second option and it works great. I now know where I made my mistake. Your answer was very insightful and I really appreciate it.